# Unusual node.js behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js

Today i saw this code, that was running in node.js environment. (>node.exe test.js)

```
var param = (typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports) || {};

(function(exports){

   console.log(exports === module.exports);

})(param);
```

And this log returned true.

Can anybody explain me such behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you expecting ?

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's wrong, but i thought that ((typeof module ..) || {}) will return true, but not "exports" object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `module` is not undefined (which it isn't since it is the default object) and `module.exports` is a truthy thing (which it is by default), then `exports` is assigned to `param` and passed to the function.

`exports` is then compared to `module.exports`, and they are the same because `module.exports` is where the object came from in the first place.

(`exports` wouldn't be the same as `module.exports` if it was running elsewhere (e.g. a browser where you get `window`, not `module`) since `{}` would be assigned to `param` instead.)

---

Update re comments on the question:

> Hmm, maybe it's wrong, but i thought that ((typeof module ..) || {}) will return true, but not "exports" object

No. `&&` will (working left to right) evaluate as the first falsey thing it tests or (if everything is truthy) the last truthy thing it tests.

`typeof module !== "undefined"` is true so it tests `module.exports`, which is also true so it returns `module.exports`.

(The `||` returns the first truthy or last falsey thing it tests, so it then returns `module.exports`)

Comment: Hmm.. I really thought that the first thing that compiler do is transforming subexpressions (typeof param == 'undefined', module.exports) in boolean, then comparing transformed values, and finally returning result (in this case true && true = true). It's my epic fail. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

```
var d = (a && b) || c
```

`d` evaluates to `b` if `a` is true. If `a` is false, `d` evaluates to `c`.